# Compiler Flag -fno-objc-arc not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting

My program is being written in Swift, with a class dependency on a "no leak SKShapeNode." This class is written in Obj-C and therefore needs compiler flags to be used. I implemented the -fno-objc-arc on the SKShapeNodeLeakFree.m file yet the compiler still doesn't detect that ARC is disabled.

[image: Compile Flag]

[image]

Comment: @Rob I'll try that, but before I do, do you think it is by any chance due to the last error of failing to import the bridging header?

Comment: More accurately, I suspect that "failure to import" error is another symptom of the same thing that is giving you the other error messages. It looks like you imported the `.m` file in the bridging header rather than the `.h` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-fno-objc-arc` setting in the "Compile Sources" of your target's "Build Phases" looks fine.

It looks like you must have incorrectly imported the `.m` file in the bridging header. You should `#import` the `.h` file in the bridging header. That would explain why you're seeing Objective-C ARC messages under the "Swift Compiler Error" section.

Comment: That was the issue. I actually imported both the .m and .h files into the header.